# Getting Heart-rate variability from Polar H10 (UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am running the BLE sample from github (Windows) and trying to get the heart rate variability from Polar H10.

However the only services and characteristics it shows me are following:

```
// first layer keys are serviceUuid's
// second layer keys are characteristicUuid's
// with their respective name/description as values
{
    "1800"    /* Generic Access */                      : {
        "2a00": "Device Name",
        "2a01": "Appearance",
        "2a02": "Peripheral Privacy Flag",
        "2a03": "Reconnection Address",
        "2a04": "Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters"
    },
    "1801"    /* Generic Attribute */                   : {
        "2a05": "Service Changed"
    },
    "180d"    /* Heart Rate */                          : {
        "2a37": "Heart Rate Measurement",
        "2a38": "Body Sensor Location"
    },
    "180a"    /* Device Information */                  : {
        "2a23": "System ID",
        "2a24": "Model Number String",
        "2a25": "Serial Number String",
        "2a26": "Firmware Revision String",
        "2a27": "Hardware Revision String",
        "2a28": "Software Revision String",
        "2a29": "Manufacturer Name String"
    },
    "180f"    /* Battery Service */                     : {
        "2a19": "Battery Level"
    },
    "6217ff4b-fb31-1140-ad5a-a45545d7ecf3" /* unknown */: {
        "6217ff4c-c8ec-b1fb-1380-3ad986708e2d": "unknown", /* read:true */ // value = 
         uInt16Array [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        "6217ff4d-91bb-91d0-7e2a-7cd3bda8a1f3": "unknown" /* write:true, 
         indicate:true, descriptors:{ descriptorUuid: "2902" }*/
     {
         /* 6172 */
         this service has all the numbers which I have no idea about. 
         Example: 10905, 10906, and etc.  
     }
}
```

Now, I know that Polar H10 does give you heart rate variability. So why it is not showing me ?

Does anyone have any idea?

**EDIT::**

```
private static ushort ParseHeartRateValue(byte[] data)
    {
        //ushort offset = 1;
        // Heart Rate profile defined flag values
        const byte heartRateValueFormat = 0x04;

        byte flags = data[0];
        ushort offset = 1;
        bool HRC2 = (flags & 1) == 1;
        if (HRC2) //this means the BPM is un uint16
        {
            short hr = BitConverter.ToInt16(data, offset);
            offset += 2;
        }
        else //BPM is uint8
        {
            byte hr = data[offset];
            offset += 1;
        }

        //see if EE is available
        //if so, pull 2 bytes

        bool ee = (flags & (1 << 3)) != 0;
        if (ee)
            offset += 2;

        // see if RR is present 
        // if so, the number of RR values is total bytes left / 2(size of uInt 16)

        bool rr = ((flags & 1 << 4) != 0);
        if (rr)
        {
            int count = (data.Length - offset) / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                //each existence of these values means an R-Wave was already detected
                //the ushort means the time (1/1024 seconds) since last r-wave

                ushort value = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, offset);

                double intervalLengthInSeconds = value / 1024.0;
                offset += 2;

            }
        }
        bool isHeartRateValueSizeLong = ((flags & heartRateValueFormat) != 0);

        if (isHeartRateValueSizeLong)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 1);
        }
        else 
        {
            return data[1];
        }

      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: First we need to know if you are able to read the notifications from characteristic 00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34f.

Comment: Yes. this characteristic gives me heart rates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can read the heartbeat in notifications than there is also the rr-interval.
The rr-interval is represented 2 bytes( uint16).
You need the rr-interval to calculate heart rate variability in your app.

To get the rr-interval you have to read the flags from the first byte you receive.
You read the flags as binary from right to left.

bit 0 = 0: Heart Rate Value Format is set to UINT8. Units:BPM (1 byte).
bit 0 = 1: Heart Rate Value Format is set to UINT16. Units:BPM (2 bytes).

bit 1 and 2: Sensor Contact Status bits. These are not relevant for this.

bit 3 = 0: Energy Expended field is not present.
bit 3 = 1: Energy Expended field is present. Format = uint16. Units: kilo Joules.

bit 4 = 0: RR-Interval values are not present.
bit 4 = 1: One or more RR-Interval values are present. Format = uint16. unit 1/1024 sec.

bit 5, 6 and 7: reserved for future use.

If your first byte  for example = 16 = 0x10  = 0b00010000 then  byte 2 = is heart rate.

Byte 3 and 4 are the rr-interval.
Byte 5 and 6 (if present) rr-interval.

To calculate heart rate variability  you have to sample the rr-interval values over a period of time and take the  Standard Deviation of those intervals.
To calculate the Standard Deviation:

```
1. Work out the Mean (the simple average of the numbers)
2. Then for each number: subtract the Mean and square the result
3. Then work out the mean of those squared differences.
4. Take the square root of that and we are done!
```

How to do that in code, I leave that up to You or you can google it.

Note:

1. Byte-pairs in SIG specifications are  Least Significant Byte First,
    so for uint16 representation in Windows swap the bytes of a byte-pair first!
2. rr-interval is not miliseconds but 1/1024 seconds. 
    This is to prevent loosing the decimal numbers in an unsigned division.

Comment: The way I get the heartbeats are just plain integers. for example 77, 81 and it changes every two seconds. It's with Microsoft's Bluetooth low energy sample C#. If you look at the image here (heart rates are marked in red and yellow) Link: https://ibb.co/m2tqrp ignore the device name. I was working with that earlier, and it's the same thing basically.

Comment: If you are using  Windows-universal-samples/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs/Scenario2_Client.xaml.cs,
 the heartbeat is filtered from the raw byte-array with the FormatValueByPresentation and ParseHeartRateValue. 
There are more bytes in received byte-array, that are not used by this sample.
That's why I explained in my answer how to get and interpret the received byte-array.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am using. [ Windows-universal-samples/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs/Scenario2_Client.xaml.cs ] But I am confused. What adjustments do I have to make into this code ? I am sure what you have explained is correct. but I don't really know how to use that.

Comment: Can I make changes to that sample code to get the heart rate variability characteristic?

Comment: I don't have a  Polar H10 so I can't test any-ting. It is absolutely possible to change the  sample code.
  Put a break-point somewhere in private static ushort ParseHeartRateValue(byte[] data) 
and inspect the content of data.
 Let me know all the bytes contained and maybe I can write some code.

Comment: Here are all the bytes in byte[]data: 0x10 ,0x46, 0x4a and 0x03

Comment: Okay tested again here are all the bytes: 0x10, 0x64, 0x41, 0x02, 0x50 and 0x02