# Decode data value of Characteristic UUID 2A37

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy

How get the RR interval value from Characteristic UUID 2A37, Service UUID 180D?

I have tried to decode the value:

`(0x) 10-54-AA-02-99-02`

I have refer to the GrooverFromHolland's explaination from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882552/getting-heart-rate-variability-from-polar-h10-uwp) to generate the bpm and rr interval.

And I have built my solution in c++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const int RR_INTERVAL_PRESENT_BIT = 4;
const int HEART_RATE_FORMAT_BIT = 0;
const int RR_INTERVAL_UNIT = 1024;

int main() {
  // characteristic UUID value
  unsigned char characteristic[] = {0x10, 0x54, 0xAA, 0x02, 0x99, 0x02};

  // read the flags
  unsigned char flags = characteristic[0];
  int heartRateFormat = (flags & (1 << HEART_RATE_FORMAT_BIT)) ? 2 : 1;
  int rrIntervalPresent = (flags & (1 << RR_INTERVAL_PRESENT_BIT)) ? 1 : 0;

  // calculate heart rate and rr-interval
  int heartRate = 0;
  int rrInterval = 0;
  int index = 1;
  if (heartRateFormat == 2) {
    heartRate = (characteristic[index] << 8) | characteristic[index + 1];
    index += 2;
  } else {
    heartRate = characteristic[index];
    index += 1;
  }

  if (rrIntervalPresent) {
    rrInterval = (characteristic[index] << 8) | characteristic[index + 1];
    rrInterval = round(rrInterval / (double)RR_INTERVAL_UNIT * 1000);
  }

  cout << "Heart rate: " << heartRate << " bpm" << endl;
  cout << "RR interval: " << rrInterval << " ms" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The output for the bpm is `84 bpm` and the rr-interval value is `42502 ms`

I have tried to compare my answer with [value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpzjA.jpg) obtained from the **rNF connect**.

And obviously my `rr-interval value is wrong. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: I have modified the Characteristic Value to `(0x) 10-54-AA-02-99-02` and the output results to match with the information observed in the screenshot of the rNF connect app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to section 3.105.2 of the document [GATT Specification Supplement](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/).

[the structure of Heart Rate Measurement characteristic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu4Jh.png)

> `10-54-AA-02-99-02`

then the value of Heart Rate Measurement characteristic is split into:

- the **Flags** field is the first octet, 0x10. i.e. 8-bits heart rate, Energy-Expended field absent, RR-Interval present.
- the **Heart Rate Measurement Value** field is the second octet, 0x54. i.e. 84 bpm.
- the oldest **RR-Interval value** field is the following two octets in little-endian, 0x02AA. i.e. 682/1024=666.016 ms
- the newest **RR-Interval value** field is the next two octets in little-endian, 0x0299. i.e. 665/1024=649.414 ms

[the structure of RR-Interval field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao1s6.png)

RR-intervel is the last field of Heart Rate Measurement characteristic therefore the code should also verify the presence of Energy-Expended field.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is about the byte order or endianness of your multi field value. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55163224/7473793) suggests that GATT attributes are supposed to be in little endian (least significant byte first). Thats also what GrooverFromHolland mentioned in your [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882552/getting-heart-rate-variability-from-polar-h10-uwp):

> Note:
>
> 1. Byte-pairs in SIG specifications are Least Significant Byte First, so
>    for uint16 representation in Windows swap the bytes of a byte-pair
>    first!

You can check this with a [Hex-to-Decimal-Converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html):

0xAA02 -> 43522
0x02AA -> 682

So you probably want to change your implementation to:

```
  if (rrIntervalPresent) {
    rrInterval = (characteristic[index + 1] << 8) | characteristic[index];
    rrInterval = round(rrInterval / (double)RR_INTERVAL_UNIT * 1000);
  }
```

Comment: Finally, it is close to the answer! But the output showing is `666 ms`, still not a correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the rr-interval is refer to byte 3 and byte 4, I have changed the `rrInterval` to `double` instead of `int`.

Refer to:

> So you probably want to change your implementation to:
>
> ```cpp
> if (rrIntervalPresent) {
>    rrInterval = (characteristic[index + 1] << 8) | characteristic[index];
>    rrInterval = round(rrInterval / (double)RR_INTERVAL_UNIT * 1000);
>  }
> ```

I have changed it to:

```cpp
  if (rrIntervalPresent) {
    rrInterval = (characteristic[index + 1] << 8) | characteristic[index + 2];
    rrInterval = rrInterval / (double)RR_INTERVAL_UNIT * 1000;
  }
```

And it shows the correct output `649.414 ms`. I'm not sure does this implementation is correct...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).